# How to cast type of gdb.value to int

Tags: python, gdb

I want to cast in python code a gdb.value which is a complicated type variable to int (this is not general type, but defined in the our code - a kind of bitfield). 
When I promped in the gdb shell itself:

> "p var"

it prints it as int, i.e. the gdb know how to cast that bitfield to int.

(Strange thing, in addition, I got when I try this command:

> int(var.cast(i.type))

When "i" is gdb.value that its type is int. The var indeed becomes int, but its value become same as the value of i).

So is someone know how to cast this gdb.value by use the knowledge of the gdb. (Or by other way..)

Thanks. This is my first question in StackOverFlow, sorry on the confusion and my weak English.

Comment: I think this needs more details, like the actual type in question.  If it is a bitfield then I'd imagine just using the Python int() operator would suffice.

Comment: Thanks, @TomTromey, but int() operator is not suffice.

Comment: Ok, it's turn out that the solution is to cast the var to a string and then to an int: int(str(var))

Comment: Yeah, that works in this case, but it isn't really the answer, in that it isn't a general technique.  It will give the wrong answer in some scenarios.  Plus it's a gross hack!  (Though this isn't always a problem :-).  Anyway more details about your code are necessary to come up with a good answer.

Answer (score 6):

What you want is:

```
int(value.cast(gdb.lookup_type('long')))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with `int(value)` giving me a signed number even when the type was explicitly unsigned. I used this to solve the problem:

`int(value) & 0xffffffffffffffff`